# Are foreign key constraints enforced on DELETE when deleting the child?

Tags: sql-server-2005, parent-child, foreign-key-relationship

I want to delete rows on a child table. I receive the error

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Address_UserDataSet".  The conflict occurred in
>   database "XYZ", table "dbo.Address", column
>   'DataSetId'. The statement has been terminated.*

I have a database structure with a parent `UserDataSet` and child  `Address` table (where a parent can have any number of childs).

There is a foreign key constraint (mentioned in the error) that requires the child's `DataSetId` to relate to a valid `UserDataSet`.

Here are the table and constraint scripts, created with `MS SQL Server  Management Studio 2008` in simplified form:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address](
    [AddressId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DataSetId] [int] NOT NULL,
        --other fields
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Address] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AddressId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

---

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDataSet](
    [DataSetId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        --other fields
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserDataSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DataSetId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

---Create the constraint

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_UserDataSet] FOREIGN KEY([DataSetId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[UserDataSet] ([DataSetId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_UserDataSet]
GO
```

**But, how can deleting a child (not the parent) be a problem in this setup?**

Can it be that the row to delete is currently invalid, probably added while the constraint was not (yet) in use), an the constraint now is enforced while deleting the child with an invalid foreign key?

Comment: There should not be any child row without a valid parent. Still do a recheck at you end.

Comment: I suggest that you generate create scrips for both tables. Recreate the tables in a test database. Test by inserting some values into the parent and child in your test database. Try to delete them and see if you can figure it out. If you can't figure out what goes wrong please repost the create table scripts and your test insert / delete statements here. Posting create / insert / delete script would say more than a description of thousand words :)

Comment: You could also do a http://SQLFiddle.com/ that shows us your problem

Comment: @mortb I have investigated the case with a unit test, and manually introduced a child with an invalid reference to the parent table. I was able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I now have proven for myself, that deleting a child with an invalid reference to a parent is failing with my constraint. But the question remains, how can this be a problem. Deleting actually makes the DB more consistent not less!

Comment: Good that you found the cause! May this be a bug in SQL server? You wouldn't want to post scritps that reproduce the problem?

Comment: @mortb scripts posted!

Comment: @Marcel: Check (1) if you have a `DELETE FROM [dbo].[UserDataSet]...` statement (2) if you have an AFTER/INSTEAD OF trigger on `[dbo].[Address]` or `[dbo].[UserDataSet]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding the constraint with `NOCHECK`?

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)...

> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints
>   against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK. *We do not recommend doing
>   this, except in rare cases*. The new constraint will be evaluated in
>   all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed
>   by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates
>   to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the
>   constraint.

Comment: Good point, this is most probably the root of the problem. But what to do now, when I am not even able to delete?

Comment: You need to ensure referential integrity before applying the foreign key constraint. What DELETE statement are you using? I would have thought you could delete child records which have an invalid parent....

Comment: The delete statement comes via Linq to SQL, so I can not tell exactly right now. But I have thought that deleting children is no problem, too - that's what this question is all about...